# Is it possible to select a buffer by the line at point?

Tags: helm, buffers, point

I'm not entirely clear that this is a good idea... but it feels like it might be.

To avoid having to think about "which buffer contains what" it might be nice to be able to select buffers by recently viewed content. The simplest definition of "recently viewed content" is where the point is.

Is there any utility that implements this feature?

The closest analogue I can think of `helm-mark-ring`.
Ideally this might include some context in the results (like `helm-org-rifle`).

Comment: `helm-global-mark-ring` might be slightly closer to want I want - this contains multiple entries for each buffer.